# Adding font awesome in pseudo class not working

Tags: css, wordpress, accordion, font-awesome, pseudo-class

I have searched and tried various solutions, but nothing is working for me. The font awesome is coming up fine in the page if using, for example:

```
<li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square"></i>List icons</li>
```

So, font awesome appears to be properly setup. But when attempting to implement into pseudo class, not working.

```
.accordion-title {
   background-color: #4d90fe;
   background-image: -webkit-linear-
   gradient(top,#4d90fe,#4787ed);
   background-image: linear-
   gradient(top,#4d90fe,#4787ed);
   border: 1px solid #3079ed;
   margin-bottom: -15px;
   padding: 15px;
   cursor: pointer;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   position: relative;
}

.accordion-title:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    top:0;
    left:-5px;
    padding-right:10px;
    content: "\f0a9"; 
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
}
```

According to the plugin, the shortcode outputs code such as:

```
<div class="accordion">
<h3 class="accordion-title">Title of accordion item</h3>
<div class="accordion-content">
    Drop-down content goes here.
</div>
<h3 class="accordion-title">Second accordion item</h3>
<div class="accordion-content">
    Drop-down content goes here.
</div>
```

So, possibly something with "h3"? I have tried for more than an hour now. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Its working here
https://jsfiddle.net/rq7uj8af/

Comment: Yes. I see, thank you. Maybe something in the javascript of the plugin keeping it from working. The actual HTML on the page showing as:  <h3 id="accordion-1-t1" class="accordion-title" role="tab" aria-controls="accordion-1-c1" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0"> + Manufacturing Process Overview</h3>  The page is here: http://gizbeat.com/motopod/operational-plan/

Comment: Check where you are including the Font Awesome CSS. You have it included 4 different times form 4 different places, and one of them is a broken link. Fix your theme to make sure **(1)** only include it once and **(2)** its the latest version.

Comment: Thank you Fluffy. I've removed a broken link and a link to an older set on cloudflare. I don't think this is the issue though, they are loading fine on the page, just not in this Accordion shortcode. I also tried not using the shortcode, but just using the HTML, still not coming in. Seems something in the javascript preventing it. I've written the plugin author to see if he can help further.

Comment: Plugin author here. The plugin doesn't do anything in JS that would prevent this from working. I'm guessing there is an issue with the CSS. Doing an inspect element I can't find the `:before` on the `.accordion-title`. What CSS file are you added that code to?

It also looks like you have another accordion plugin. That may be conflicting.

Comment: Hello Phil, I noticed the same thing. It doesn't appear to be loaded at all. I'm adding it to the theme's custom CSS (Appearance > Customize). Any changes I make to the the main Accordion CSS here are immediately showing (eg, not a cache issue). But not the :before pseudo class. It's as if I'm naming it wrong or something...

Comment: I think you are naming it wrong. I see `.accordion:before` and `.title:before` but no `.accordion-title:before` in that CSS.

Comment: Right. I was playing around trying different things. It's back to accordion-title:before now. But still not applying.

Comment: Yes. I've disabled the other accordion plugin. Still no go. Totally bizarre. the only thing I could figure is i've somehow got the css name wrong, but it seems to be right.

Comment: That seems to have done it. I think the issue is with the `content: &quot;\f0a9&quot;;` part. It looks like it is escaping the quotes. Try using this: `content: "\f0a9";`.

Comment: I've put it in quotes and it's still coming up all funky escaped from the quotes. Pasting the proper code in debugger works. Maybe I'll try in the main CSS?

Comment: Okay. I've put it in the main CSS and now good to go. Thanks for your help Phil. Regards

Answer (score 0):

What I think is your css is being overwritten by jquery-ui css
Try debugging with inspect element, to find out.
Try using **!important** or a **parent class** to give importance to your css rules

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added !important to all in the :before element. Still nothing. Actually the :before element doesn't appear to be applied/loading at all according to debugger. I've written to the plugin author to see if he can shed some light on it.

Comment: You are such a wonderful helper, seems like webpack is doing some re-writing on some of my stuff: 

Added the !important rule after - font-family: FontAwesome !important;

now it is working again!